# New products doesn't have .html at the end of the url

Tags: magento-1.8, url, html, category-products

A few months ago I changed the `Use Categories Path for Product URLs` to no to avoid duplicate urls.

Products had .html at the end of the url with or without the category. At this time, I do still have the .html sufix enabled but I've noticed that the new products I upload to Magento doesn't have it.

What I would like is to show all products with .html at the end and of course, without the category on the path.

A screenshot of the configuration as it is at this moment:

[image]

Comment: if you have multiple store then change the scope to store and check the settings

Comment: I do only have one store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why it did not have the `.html` at the end. Magento products needed to be reindexed. I reindexed these products, not throw Magento admin panel, but with Store Manager. This tool has the option of reindexing products after importing them. Everything looked to be fine with that reindex but it seems it did not.

So I just reindexed products throw Magento admin panel and then updated cache and it is fine now.